# How to erase part of the circle in java.awt.Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

my problem is that i want to make something like clock like animated timer

i coded the whole clock but i couldn't figure out how to only draw part of the circle or adjust it .

i don't the clock as is but i only need to know how delete or draw part of the circle so i can describe the time graphiclly as i noticed that when i used swing worker to update the time in text in a label it seems to have a notch mysterious notch !! so any help will make me get over those two props will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely looking for the `fillArc` method, where you can specify the start and end angles which you wish to draw.

Full Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillArc-int-int-int-int-int-int-